# How can I be notified of upvotes when I have reached the daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, support

I know that we have a daily cap on reputation gain, but this is not what I'm interested in.

Pretty much like the title says, how can I be notified of the upvotes/downvotes in my posts when i have reached the daily cap? The notifier on the top bar basically only informas me of reputation changes, not of the activity and performance of my posts.

Is there a way to keep track of this?

Comment: Notified? No....but you can still see them on your "reputation" tab of your profile.

Comment: Notifications? Not without loading some kind of tampermonkey tool. You can, of course just look at them manually; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/83101/sekhemty?tab=reputation

Comment: ["I want to get notified about upvotes and downvotes, even after I hit the reputation cap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214034/i-want-to-get-notified-about-upvotes-and-downvotes-even-after-i-hit-the-reputat)

Comment: This belongs on Meta.SE, but it's pretty much a duplicate of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214034/299342).

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @Valorum they're not tools, they're scripts

Comment: @Edlothiad - I cherish my ignorance on the subject.

Comment: @Edlothiad - if you want Valorum to be aware of the subject, you need to write a junior novelization on the topic